# Trying to send form data to a php file to process and post to API

Tags: php, html

I am trying to setup a form to post the data to a php file which will then make an API call, I am pretty close I think any help appreciated.

When I have been doing testing the form seems to post to the php file however nothing seems to happen from then on. I was going to try and print out the data string to see if that is correct ??

The only part which is missing is the first part of the url which I have but cannot post on here

here is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
label, input, textarea { display: block; float: left; width: 150px; margin: 5px; }
label { clear: left; text-align: right; }
input[type="submit"] { width: 60px; margin: 10px 0 0 165px; clear: left; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>New Account Creation</h2>
<form action="sonian.php" method="post">
<label>User name (required)</label> <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
<label>Password</label> <input type="text" name="password" value="" />
<label>First Name</label> <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" />
<label>Last Name</label> <input type="text" name="last_name" value="" />
<label>Email</label> <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
<label>Address Line 1</label> <input type="text" name="address1" value="" />
<label>Address Line 2</label> <input type="text" name="address2" value="" />
<label>City</label> <input type="text" name="city" value="" />
<label>County</label> <input type="text" name="state" value="" />
<label>Postcode</label> <input type="text" name="zip" value="" />
<label>Phone Number</label> <input type="text" name="phone" value="" />
<label>Sub Domain</label> <input type="text" name="sub_domain" value="" />
<label>Account Name</label> <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
<label>Number of Users</label> <input type="text" name="number_of_users" value="" />
<label>Account Type</label> <input type="text" name="organization_type_id" value="" />
<div class="field required clear">

<label class="_">Account type</label>
<select id="account_organization_type_id" name="account[organization_type_id]"><option value="1500">Commercial</option>
<option value="1501">Non-Profit</option>
<option value="1502">Education</option>
<option value="1503">Government</option></select>
</div>
<div class="field clear">
<label class="inline"><input name="account[uses_exchange]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="account_uses_exchange" name="account[uses_exchange]" type="checkbox" value="1" />&nbsp;Exchange
</label>
<label class="inline"><input name="account[uses_groupwise]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="account_uses_groupwise" name="account[uses_groupwise]" type="checkbox" value="1" />&nbsp;GroupWise
</label>
<label class="inline"><input name="account[uses_notes]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="account_uses_notes" name="account[uses_notes]" type="checkbox" value="1" />&nbsp;Noteworthy
</label>
<label class="inline"><input name="account[uses_zimbra]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="account_uses_zimbra" name="account[uses_zimbra]" type="checkbox" value="1" />&nbsp;Zimbra
</label>
```

IMail Server

```
</label>
<label class="inline"><input name="account[uses_scalix]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="account_uses_scalix" name="account[uses_scalix]" type="checkbox" value="1" />&nbsp;Scalix
</label>
<label class="inline"><input name="account[uses_gmail]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="account_uses_gmail" name="account[uses_gmail]" type="checkbox" value="1" />&nbsp;Gmail Apps
</label>
<label class="inline"><input name="account[uses_sunone]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="account_uses_sunone" name="account[uses_sunone]" type="checkbox" value="1" />&nbsp;SunONE
</label>
<label class="inline"><input name="account[uses_hosted_exchange]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="account_uses_hosted_exchange" name="account[uses_hosted_exchange]" type="checkbox" value="1" />&nbsp;Hosted Exchange
</label>
<label class="inline"><input name="account[uses_kerio]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="account_uses_kerio" name="account[uses_kerio]" type="checkbox" value="1" />&nbsp;Kerio
</label>
<label class="inline"><input name="account[uses_other]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="account_uses_other" name="account[uses_other]" type="checkbox" value="1" />&nbsp;Other
</label>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the php code

```
    <?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
    $strPost = "";
    //create string with form POST data
    $strPost = "Username=" . urlencode($_POST['username'])
    . "&Password=" . urlencode($_POST['password'])
    . "&First Name=" . urlencode($_POST['first_name'])
    . "&Last Name=" . urlencode($_POST['last_name'])
    . "&Email=" . urlencode($_POST['email'])
    . "&Address Line 1=" . urlencode($_POST['address1'])
    . "&Address Line 2=" . urlencode($_POST['address2'])
    . "&City=" . urlencode($_POST['city'])
    . "&County=" . urlencode($_POST['state'])
    . "&Postcode=" . urlencode($_POST['zip'])
    . "&Phone Number=" . urlencode($_POST['phone'])
    . "&Sub Domain=" . urlencode($_POST['sub_domain'])
    . "&Account Name=" . urlencode($_POST['name'])
    . "&Number of Users=" . urlencode($_POST['number_of_users'])
    . "&Account Type=" . urlencode($_POST['organization_type_id'])
    . "&Email System=" . urlencode($_POST['uses_exchange']);
    //set POST URL
    $url = "https://url/api/accounts.xml";
    //intialize cURL and send POST data
    $ch = @curl_init();
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $strPost);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    @curl_exec($ch);
    @curl_close($ch);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Why are you suppressing warnings in all your `curl_` calls? Also, try setting `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER);` and then `$result = curl_exec($ch);` What's the value of $result?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something messy about the form.

On the same line there is a hidden input with the same name as the checkbox right next to it.

```
<input name="account[uses_exchange]" type="hidden" value="0" />
<input id="account_uses_exchange" name="account[uses_exchange]" type="checkbox" value="1" />&nbsp;Exchange
```

How can the php file make sense of that?

Also, on the  php processing you have the var

```
. "&Email System=" . urlencode($_POST['uses_exchange']);
```

But I think you are sending the name of this thing as an array value.

```
 name="account[uses_exchange]"
```

So, I guess you should decide about if you want to use hidden values or if you want to use an array of check boxes.

Then loop through your array on the other side in the php processing.

Example

```
 foreach($_POST['account'] as $k => $v)
    echo "<br>$k => $v";
```

Produces:

```
organization_type_id => 1500
uses_exchange => 1
uses_groupwise => 1
uses_notes => 1
uses_zimbra => 1
uses_scalix => 1
uses_gmail => 1
uses_sunone => 1
uses_hosted_exchange => 1
uses_kerio => 1
uses_other => 1
```